# Is it possible to design a Java EE web application without using java servlets? Do JSF and Facelets are an alternative?

Tags: jsf, servlets, facelets

Is it possible to design a Java EE web application without using Java servlets? Do JSF and Facelets are an alternative?

Comment: Those things are built on top of servlets. You do not have to write any servlets directly yourself, if that is your question.

Answer (score 2):

i guess you need to polish your background in understanding the relation between  servlet and jsp and jsf. You can take a look at BalusC's great post "[What is the difference between JSF, JSP and Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp)"

JSF pages are built on top of servlets, as an example JSF provides the FacesServlet as the  request response controller. Without any knowledge of them you can write web applications.

On the other hand each Jsf version requires a servlet version. As an example jsf 2.0 and above requires servlet 3.0 specifications, and should be backwards compatible with Servlet 2.5.